# Investigate whether the set is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

I am supposed to investigate whether the set is bounded: 
$$
M=\left \{   x\in \mathbb{R};x=\frac{(n+3)!-(n+1)!}{(n+3)!+n!}+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2}-3\sqrt{n}}+\frac{\mathrm{arctg}\frac{n-1}{n}}{n^{2}+1}, n\in \mathbb{N}                 \right \}.
$$
What I did was to put all three fractions into absolute values and bounded the first two fractions with 1: however, I don't know what to do with the third fraction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$\arctan$ is bounded by $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence the third term is also bounded.

Comment: Only the numerator is bounded by $\frac{\pi }{2}$, right? What about the denominator?

Comment: Bound it by $1$?